# CoreLocation Non-iBeacon Bluetooth device scan

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-location

I want to find Bluetooth devices and get RSSI values using certain period time. I can scan iBeacons. But I also want to find the other Bluetooth devices (like an iPhone device). How can I scan for all devices using CoreLocation?

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedAlways {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func startScanning() {
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "XXXXX")!
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 0, minor: 0, identifier: "XXXXX")

        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        extendBackgroundRunningTime()
        if beacons.count > 0 {
            print(beacons)
            updateDistance(beacons[0].proximity)
        } else {
            updateDistance(.unknown)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your code? What did you try? What's not working? There are plenty of tutorials/questions about CoreBluetooth.

Comment: You need CoreBluetootj

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot scan Bluetooth device with this method.You can only scan bluetooth device with Core Bluetooth Frame work.
Go through the below tutorial for bluetooth.
[Press here for link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/231-core-bluetooth-tutorial-for-ios-heart-rate-monitor)